# drawImage not showing an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, drawimage

```
function render()
{
    canvasBackground.drawImage(images[0], 0, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
}

function initImages(paths)
{
    requiredImages = paths.length;
    for (i in paths)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = paths[i];
        images[i] = img;
        images[i].onload = function ()
        {
            doneImages++;
        }
    }
}

function checkImages()
{
    if (doneImages >= requiredImages)
    {
        loop();
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            checkImages();
        }, 1);
    }
}

initImages(["picture.png"]);
checkImages();
```

I did this exactly but nothing is showing up, any idea how to fix this?

Btw I didn't show you the loop functions which in turn runs the render function.

Comment: Also I dont get any errors or anything, its just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a refactored version of your code.**

It increments `doneImages` until it's equal to `paths.length` (at which point all the images are fully loaded).

Then `render` is called on each image index.

BTW, your render function is distorting your images by stretching them.  I assume that's intentional?

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvasBackground=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var images=[];
var paths=[];
paths.push('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/animated.gif');
paths.push('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/ball1.png');

initImages(paths);

function render(i)
{
  canvasBackground.drawImage(images[i], 0, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
}

function initImages(paths)
{
  var doneImages=0;
  for (i in paths)
  {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = paths[i];
    images[i] = img;
    images[i].onload = function ()
    {
      // just return if all the images aren't loaded yet
      if(++doneImages<paths.length){return;}

      for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){ render(i); }

    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the problem wasnt the image but the canvas that was stretched out and made the image not appear at the position I had it positioned. When I tried to make the canvas "fullscreen" with css and javascript something messed everything up.